# Apache OpenEJB error

Tags: apache

tengo un error que no me permite instalar el servidor OpenEJB de Apache. Tengo bajado el .zip para instalarlo, pero cuando ejecuto el "Start.bat" (para correr el servidor) simplemente abre y cierra la consola, no hace nada. Abrí la consola y lo ejecute desde ahí y este es el error que me tira. Les adjunto una imagen para que vean cual es y ver si me pueden ayudar.

Muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDITADO:

Esto es lo que me aparece cuando pongo echo %OPENEJB_HOME%

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Abre el cmd y dale `echo %OPENEJB_HOME%` para verificar que la variable de entorno esta correctamente configurada

Comment: Lo más rápido creo que es configurar el loggin y revisa que sucede al iniciar el servidor!

Comment: Y como haría eso? Perdón la ignorancia, pero soy nuevo en esto de los servidores.


PD: Probé cambiar la carpeta en donde tenia el servidor (C:/Apache OpenEJB/apache-openejb-4-7-4) al C: (C:/apache-openejb-4.7.4) y anduvo, pero quisiera saber si el setear esa variable HOME me permitiría cambiar de directorio esa carpeta (apache-openejb-4.7.4).